# Angular 4: ngComponentOutlet - pass dynamically the value from an array

Tags: angular, components, ngfor

Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/JvXBLOVaeaYO5bmMQa6a?p=preview

In the plunker I got 3 boxes generate from an array ngFor loop.
Each box has an event listener attached.
When you click on the box I would like to generate a component. the generated component needs to be generated based on the component name that is specified in the array.

In the array I specify what component should be loaded in the div that the user clicks.

Each div has an ng-container where the generated component should be inserted in.

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="items.componentSlider"></ng-container>
```

Currently if you click the button change component it will swap the component in

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="alert"></ng-container>
```

But I would like to initialise inside my in the loop.

**I would like to generate a component and assign/inject it to the div that I clicked on.**

You can see in the items array i got 2 of the  same component specified 'sliderComponent' , so in the loop when I click I would like to generate a component and if two divs have the same component for them to **independent**.

How can I pass dynamically inside ngComponentOutlet the data so it load me the component?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Angular version 4</h1>


    <div *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="loadComponent(item)">
          <strong> When you click here, 
          I should load the <span style="color:red"> {{item.name}} </span>
          component below</strong> <br />

          <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="items.componentSlider"></ng-container>

      <br />
    </div>


    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="alert"></ng-container>
    <button (click)="changeComponent()">Change component</button>
  `
})
export class App {
  items:Array<any> = [
    {
      name: 'slider'
      componentSlider: sliderComponent
    },
    {
      name: 'user'
      componentSlider: usersComponent
    },
{
  name: 'slider'
  componentSlider: sliderComponent
},

    ]

  alert = AlertSuccessComponent;
  dynamicComponent = 'xxxxx';

  changeComponent() {
    this.alert = AlertDangerComponent;
  }

  loadComponent(item){
    this.dynamicComponent = item

    this.alert = item.componentSlider

  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'alert-danger',
  template: `
    <p>Alert danger</p>
  `,
})
export class AlertDangerComponent {

}


@Component({
  selector: 'slider',
  template: `
    <p>slider</p>
  `,
})
export class sliderComponent {

}


@Component({
  selector: 'users',
  template: `
    <p>users</p>
  `,
})
export class usersComponent {

}
```

Comment: you may find [this](https://hackernoon.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02#4ebb) helpful

Comment: at this moment the directive does not allow to pass attributes. There is a PR  that will allow to get a ref to the dynamically create component and configure inputs on it. https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/15362. Use ComponentFactoryResolver to create components and pass attrs

Comment: if the component is string means how can i load it in expression ex:items:Array<any> = [
    {
      name: 'slider'
      componentSlider: 'sliderComponent'
    }
    ]

Answer (score 0):

I am fasing the same problem. (9/20/2017)

Currently there is no solution that uses the standart angular4 modules.

What worked for me was the https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-component.

Please run the plunker for a live demo:
https://plnkr.co/edit/uaYuAfki8dkxcRFzO2bN

```
    // our root app component
    import { Component, Input, NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';


    @Component({
      selector: 'my-dynamic-component1', template: `Austria Component [first]  <br>
    <p><strong>transferred 1:</strong> {{context.arg1}}</p>
    <p><strong>transferred 2:</strong> {{context.arg2}}</p>
    ` })
    class Austria {
      @Input() context: any;
    }

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-dynamic-component1', template: `Germany Component [second] <br>
    <p><strong>transferred 1:</strong> {{context.arg1}}</p>
    <p><strong>transferred 2:</strong> {{context.arg2}}</p>
    ` })
    class Germany {
      @Input() context: any;
    }

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      template: `<ndc-dynamic [ngComponentOutlet]="component"
                              [ndcDynamicInputs]="inputs"
                              ></ndc-dynamic>`
    })
    class MyComponent implements OnInit {
      public component = Austria;
      public currentIteration = 0;
      private inputs = {
        context: {
          arg1: 'value1',
          arg2: 1234567890,
        }
      };
      ngOnInit() {
        this.updateContextValues();
        window.setInterval(()=>{
          this.updateContextValues();
          // switch between the two components
          this.component = (this.component === Austria) ? Germany : Austria;
        }, 1000);
      }
      updateContextValues(){
        this.currentIteration++;
        this.inputs.context.arg1 = 'value' + this.currentIteration;
      }
    }

    import { DynamicModule } from 'ng-dynamic-component';
    @NgModule({
      imports: [ BrowserModule, DynamicModule.withComponents([ Austria, Germany ]) ],
      declarations: [ MyComponent, Austria, Germany ],
      bootstrap: [ MyComponent ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```